# Blog Read More with HTML how to achieve

Tags: blog

I had got a lot of news with this html formating, and i want to see button read more, after html formating:

[image]

I tried first two in this article, but it don't work with HTML:

[Blog Read More Link and Summary of Body](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84377/blog-read-more-link-and-summary-of-body)

Comment: Is it don't work at all or it does not render read more link?

Comment: It render link with some of HTML, but not all.

Comment: In first i dont see anithing, And in secound I see but without html.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/1156/

```
body, input{
    font-family: Calibri, Arial;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

a {
    color: #0254EB
}

a:visited {
   color: #0254EB
}

#header h2 {
    color: white;
    background-color: #00A1E6;
    margin:0px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.comment {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
    margin: 10px;
}

a.morelink {
    text-decoration:none;
    outline: none;
}

.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: But with only css I worry that  don't manage this.

Comment: css  is sample one..try that link i have shared with you...You can see the example